# new object will be empty

Tags: node.js, typescript

I can't get this code to work.

```ts
import "reflect-metadata";

export class Castable {
  [key: string]: any;
  constructor(source: any) {
    console.log("source: ");
    console.log(source);
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(source).forEach((propertyKey) => {
      const designType = Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", this, propertyKey);
      const customType = Reflect.getMetadata("custom:type", this, propertyKey);
      const type = customType !== undefined ? customType : designType;
      this[propertyKey] = this.convert(
        source[propertyKey],
        propertyKey,
        type,
        0
      );
    });
    console.log("after constructor this: ");
    console.log(this);
  }

  private convert(
    source: any,
    propertyKey: string,
    type: any,
    depth: number
  ): any {
    if (type === undefined) {
      return source;
    }
    switch (type.name) {
      case "Number":
        return Number(source);
      case "String":
        return String(source);
      case "Boolean":
        return source.toString() === "true";
      default:
        return new type(source);
    }
  }
}

/**  --- TreeRoot ---  */
export class MyConfigRoot extends Castable {
  result: boolean;
  count: number;
}

function init() {
  const json = '{"result":true, "count":32}';
  let input = JSON.parse(json);
  let newR = new MyConfigRoot(input);
  console.log("after new: ");
  console.log(newR);
}

init();
```

After getting the type with Reflect.getMetadata, type checking is performed.
This code would result in an empty new object.

```
> node ./dist/test.js

source:
{ result: true, count: 32 }
after constructor this:
MyConfigRoot { result: true, count: 32 }
after new:
MyConfigRoot { result: undefined, count: undefined }
```

The assignment in constractor seems to succeed, but actually comes up empty.
It is actually deeper than that, but it is a minimal structure to isolate the problem. Why would it be empty?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70250602/3617380

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the `useDefineForClassFields` compilerOptions, or the lack of it. Because if not manually set, its default value is correlated to `target` option. From [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#useDefineForClassFields):

> This flag is used as part of migrating to the upcoming standard version of class fields. TypeScript introduced class fields many years before it was ratified in TC39. The latest version of the upcoming specification has a **different runtime behavior** to TypeScript’s implementation but the same syntax.
>
> This flag switches to the upcoming ECMA runtime behavior.
>
> Default:
> `true` if target is ES2022 or higher, including ESNext, `false` otherwise.

Feel free to read the detailed [backstory](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier). Short explainer to your case goes like this:

```
/**  --- TreeRoot ---  */
class MyConfigRoot extends Castable {
  result: boolean; // 
  count: number;
}
```

These type-only annotations in TS used to be harmless and have no JS runtime effect. However when `useDefineForClassFields` is introduced, the compilation result changes.

- `useDefineForClassFields: true`

```
/**  --- TreeRoot ---  */
class MyConfigRoot extends Castable {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        Object.defineProperty(this, "result", {
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
            writable: true,
            value: void 0
        });
        Object.defineProperty(this, "count", {
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
            writable: true,
            value: void 0
        });
    }
}
```

- `useDefineForClassFields: false`

```
/**  --- TreeRoot ---  */
class MyConfigRoot extends Castable {
}
```

Thus the behavior you observed.

---

Besides tuning TS compiler option, you can also use the `declare` keyword in your TS v3.7+ code to fine control the JS compilations.

```
/**  --- TreeRoot ---  */
class MyConfigRoot extends Castable {
  declare result: boolean; //  declare keyword
  count: number;
}

// Now `useDefineForClassFields: true` COMPILES TO:

/**  --- TreeRoot ---  */
class MyConfigRoot extends Castable {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        Object.defineProperty(this, "count", {
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
            writable: true,
            value: void 0
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for the detailed answer with working example!